# get date jxdatepicker desired format set in jlabel

Tags: java, swing

I am new with jxDatePicker.
I work with netbeans picked jxDatePicker and selected date.

Display (Wed 11/05/2014) format.

How to set jxDatePicker format("yyyy-MM-dd")(expect).And how to get the value and set in jLabel.

```
JXDatePicker datePicker = new JXDatePicker();
datePicker.setFormats("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I tried code but not working.

Answer (score 3):

```
private void jXDatePicker1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Calendar cals = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    formater.format(jXDatePicker1.getDate());
    jLabel.setText(formater.format(cals.getTime()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//here the code to get value of jxdatepicker in normal date format

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    jxdatepicker.setFormats(dateFormat);
    DateFormat sysDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String date_to_store = sysDate.format(d1.getDate()).toString(); 
    System.out.println(date_to_store);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a String array in `setFormats()` call.

```
datePicker.setFormats(new String[]{"yyyy-MM-dd"});
```